# Search for (Python)Project that compares Reinforcement Learning vs. DeepRL

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

There is Reinforcementlearning without any Neural Network (like Q-Learning) and there is Deep-Reinforcementlearning (like Deep Q-Learning).

Is there already a Project which provides a comparison between two approaches on the same problem? Maybe a small Python project or a blogpost I'm not aware off...

I only find master thesis on this topic but without any code, see:

https://www.kth.se/social/files/58865ec8f27654607fb6e9a4/PFinnman_MWinberg_dkand16.pdf?fbclid=IwAR0PDJHx6e04xtamDG7IjHWIZAcdP2Qg_xsgJO0G0_kHWPVgVFS99eePP7g

Answer (score 0):

You may have heard about **Sutton-Barto** book on [**reinforcement-learning-an-introduction**](http://www.incompleteideas.net/book/the-book.html). In this book, you will find a lot of examples, on `Q` learning using `table` as well as with `neural-network`.

There are also comparison between many other algorithm like SARSA, TD, Q, value-function etc. In that link, you will find code repository which have solution of almost all problem from the book.

Feel free to ask question.